# how to add string to variable in php?

Tags: php

i just need on small info i want just add '@' to one variable and and put add thing into one variable. i am adding small php code to here please suggest me.

```
 <?php
    $email34 = $row['email'];
    $rem = '@gmail.com';
    $trim_email = str_replace($rem ,'', $email34);
    $tag_name ="@".$trim_emial.; 
    echo $tag_name;
 ?>
```

but i am getting only @ as output;
but my out should be "@mahesh1" if any have idea about this code please help me. thank you advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is so much spelling mistakes in the variables... try below given code

```
<?php $email34 = $row['email'];
$rem = '@gmail.com';
$trim_email = str_replace($rem ,'', $email34);
$tag_name ="@".$trim_email; 
echo $tag_name;
?>
```